# Como subir archivos de manera masiva a un FTP con PHP

Tags: php, ftp

Estoy tratando de subir varios archivos que tengo en una carpeta a un FTP pero no me permite hacerlo sino que no sube los archivos y no da ningún aviso de error, son varios archivos que debo subir de tipo XML, y por eso el uso del ciclo, este el código que uso:

```
<?php
// variables
# FUNCIONES FTP
# CONSTANTES
define("SERVER","servidor.com"); //IP o Nombre del Servidor
define("PORT",21); //Puerto
define("USER","user"); //Nombre de Usuario
define("PASSWORD","pass"); //Contraseña de acceso
define("PASV",true); //Activa modo pasivo
$destination_file = "/orders/registered/";
$source_file = "C:/Gensyscg/Pedidos/Ejecutados/";
```

```
// conexión
$conn_id = ftp_connect(SERVER,PORT);
// login
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id,USER,PASSWORD); //Se loguea al Servidor FTP
// conexión
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { 
       $log_error=fopen('C:/Gensyscg/Pedidos/log/log_error.txt','a');
        fwrite($log_error,"\n".date('m-d-Y h:i:s a', time())." - Conexión al FTP con errores,  Intentando conectar a ".SERVER);fclose($log_error);
       exit; 
   } else {
       echo "Conectado a ".SERVER;
   }
```

Aqui es donde se inicia el proceso para subir los archivos

```
    // LISTA DE PRODUCTOS PROCESADOS
    $arrFiles = array();
    $dir_ped = opendir('C:/Gensyscg/Pedidos/Ejecutados/');     
    if ($dir_ped) {
        while (($entry = readdir($dir_ped)) !== FALSE) {
            $extension = pathinfo($entry, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            if($extension === 'xml')
            {   
                $arrFiles[] = $entry;
            }
        }
    }
// // archivo a copiar/subir
foreach($arrFiles as $files)
{
    $files = $source_file.$files;
    $destination = $destination_file.$files;
    $upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination, $files, FTP_BINARY);
    // estado de subida/copiado
    if (!$upload) { 
            $log_error=fopen('C:/Gensyscg/Pedidos/log/log_error.txt','a');
            fwrite($log_error,"\n".date('m-d-Y h:i:s a', time())." - Error al subir el archivo a ".SERVER);fclose($log_error);       
       } else {
            $log_success=fopen('C:/Gensyscg/Pedidos/log/log_success.txt','a');   
            fwrite($log_success,"\n".date('m-d-Y h:i:s a', time())."Archivo $files se ha subido exitosamente a ".SERVER." en $destination_file");fclose($log_success);
       }
}
// cerramos
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

Comment: Activa temporalmente el reporte/muestra de errores en pantalla, poniendo esto al inicio del script: `ini_set('display_errors', '1');
 ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` luego agrega a la pregunta todo lo que veas en pantalla pulsando en [edit], cambiando posibles datos sensibles. Conviene que para estos casos revises el log de errores.

Comment: Hola, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Definiste mas no usaste el modo pasivo; es decir, después de usar `ftp_login()` te falta `ftp_pasv($conn_id, PASV);`.